# Assigning values to ArrayList using mapTo

Tags: arraylist, kotlin

Previously I was using this code:

```
private val mItems = ArrayList<Int>()
(1..item_count).mapTo(mItems) { it }

/*
 mItems will be: "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., item_count"
*/
```

Now, I am using a class instead of `Int`, but the class has `Int` member with name `id`.

```
class ModelClass(var id: Int = 0, var status: String = "smth")
```

So how can I use this method to fill the `ArrayList` in similar way?

```
//?
private val mItems = ArrayList<ModelClass>()
(1..item_count).mapTo(mItems) { mItems[position].id = it } // Something like this
//?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [`mapTo` documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-to.html):

> Applies the given transform function to each element of the original collection and appends the results to the given destination.

Therefore, you just need to return the elements you want:

```
(1..item_count).mapTo(mItems) { ModelClass(it) }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are OK with any `MutableList` (which is often `ArrayList` or similar):

```
val mItems1 = MutableList(item_count) { i -> i }
val mItems2 = MutableList(item_count) { ModelClass(it) }
```

Comment: I don't see a constructor that works like this and I can't get it to compile. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are right, it works only for `MutableList`, sorry

Comment: Ah, makes sense.